# Should we stress which specific HTTP response code to return when there's an error?

Tags: node.js, rest, http, api-design, http-response-codes

I am trying to determine which HTTP status code to return to the rest client under various error conditions. I find this task to be very stressful as reading HTTP status code definition is like reading the constitution, everyone can interpret the same thing differently.

For example, some people say to return 404 Not Found if the requested resource cannot be found, whereas some people say it shouldn't because it means endpoint is not available.

Another example is in this post:
[What HTTP response code to use for failed POST request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47269601/what-http-response-code-to-use-for-failed-post-request), it is recommended by the answer to return 422 Unprocessable Entity instead of a generic error 400 Bad Request.

My question is, why not just start simple and return 400 Bad Request for all errors, provide context within response body, and only to include more HTTP status code when there is obvious value?

For example, previously we returned 200 OK when app access token has expired. To help app resolve this issue we provided an internal error ID in the response so client can request a new access token with their refresh token. But we realize that by returning 401 Unauthorized instead client's implementation can be much simpler because of the library that it uses. Now we think there is an obvious value here by adding a new HTTP status code.

So to summarize my question again, is there a need to stress which specific HTTP status code to return? What's wrong with returning 400 in my second example if context is provided in the response body?

Comment: While response codes in the 4xx range are often considered failures caused by clients, I like Jim Webber's take on it where he considers status codes as [coordination data](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=16m50s) where at each step in the process we know whether something went well or badly and in case something goes badly it gives us feedback on how to address the badness.

Answer (score 2):

> I find this task to be very stressful as reading HTTP status code definition is like reading the constitution, everyone can interpret the same thing differently.

The most important thing is to recognize that HTTP status codes are of the [transporting documents over a network](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=3m8s) domain, not your business domain.  Remember, the basic idea is that every resource on every web server understands the status codes the *same way*, and general purpose components (like web browsers) don't need any special knowledge of a specific resource in order to interpret the status codes correctly.

The *body* of the response is how you communicate resource specific information to the client.

> My question is, why not just start simple and return 400 Bad Request for all errors, provide context within response body, and only to include more HTTP status code when there is obvious value?

"Obvious value" is the whole trick, isn't it?  Which is to say, yes, you can use [400 Bad Request](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.1) for all client errors, in much the same way that you can use POST for all requests.  But doing that conceals meaning that general purpose components can take advantage of.

Back in the day, [401 Unauthorized](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-3.1) was the go to example for why you would want a specific status code -- a browser which had been anonymously submitting requests would know that this particular request needs authorization credentials, and by looking at other meta data in the response could work out how to compose a new request (for instance, by asking the human operator for a username and password, then encoding that information into the appropriate header).

Note the target audience here; we weren't expecting the human to understand what 401 means; we were expecting the *general purpose tool* to understand what 401 means, and to act appropriately.  Your correct use of the meta data in the transport documents over a network domain improves my experience by giving my general purpose client the information it needs to be smart.

Please note in the above the emphasis on information about the transfer of documents.  When you are trying to communicate information about problems in *your* domain, those details do belong in the response body.  [403 Forbidden](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.3) (I understand what you asked, and I'm not willing to do it) shows up quite often when a particular request would violate your domain's protocol.

We don't, after all, expect a general purpose component to have customization specific to *our* domain.